# loop para obter data

Tags: php

Olá pessoal tenho um sistema de boleto bancario.
preciso realizar um carnê, porém não estou conseguindo executar a função strtotime corretamente pra gerar os vencimento. =\

```
<?php
$parcelas =11;
$now = "18/07/2018";
for($i = 0, $meses = 1 ;$i < $parcelas; $i++, $meses++){
$vencimento = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("$now +".$meses." months"));
} 
?>
```

o resultado acima começa com: 01/01/1970
O resultado esperado seria 18/07/2018 + 30 dias e por ai vai.
Obrigado pessoal! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro problema é o formato atual da data na variável `$now`, você precisa convertê-la para um formato sem as `/`:

```
$now="18/07/2018";
$now=str_replace("/","-",$now);
```

Em seguida você vai converter `$now` para o formato padrão `Y-m-d`:

```
$now=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($now));
```

Agora sim, você pode somar os meses a essa data, dentro do loop `for`:

```
for($i = 0, $meses = 1 ;$i < $parcelas; $i++, $meses++){
    $vencimento=date("d/m/Y",strtotime("$now + $meses month"));
    echo $vencimento."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O formato de data `dd/mm/aaaa` não existe, somente o `mm/dd/aaaa`, então, para o PHP, você está informando o dia 7 do mês 18, que não existe, por isso a data vai para o ano 1970.

Substitua para `18-07-2018` que deve funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado anderson.